# Object variable or with block variable set (stops after approx 80 searches)

Tags: vba

I am running the infamous "google search & return" code but my vba stops after bout 80 records. then I have to restart. Can anyone see what is wrong in here? Sometime I have to wait until the code will allow itself to run again.

```
Sub XMLHTTP()
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim rngCt As Long
Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
For rngCt = 2 To lastRow

url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(rngCt, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
XMLHTTP.send
DoEvents
html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)
Set link = objH3.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)

str_text = Replace(Replace(link.innerHTML, "", ""), "", "")

Cells(rngCt, 2) = str_text
Cells(rngCt, 3) = link.href
DoEvents
Set objResultDiv = Nothing
Set objH3 = Nothing
Set link = Nothing
DoEvents
Next rngCt
end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time
Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does it break on?  Did you try checking the value of your variables on the line that it breaks on?

Comment: it does not highlight any error for me. it seems to stop between line 60 and 80. right now i am getting the error i mentioned about as soon as I execute the macro.

Comment: i should also note, that I am not proficient in vba. someone else helped me with this code.

Answer (score 0):

"Object variable or with block variable set" is a "null reference error" and it means that you are trying to use a property or method of an object when the object itself is null (`Nothing` in VBA).

For instance, if I have a `Person` object and it has properties `Name`, `Age`, `Gender`, `Weight`, and `Height` and it has a `SayMyName()` method, then I could use it like this:

```
Dim aPerson As Person
Set aPerson = New Person()
...
```

Then later, you could use its properties or methods like this:

```
MsgBox(aPerson.Name)
```

However, if `aPerson` was null (`Nothing`), then you would get the null reference error you got:

```
Set aPerson=Nothing
MsgBox(aPerson.Name) 'Null ref error will happen here.
```

The only way you're going to figure out what is going on here is if you can observe the state of your variables when the error happens.  Try this:

In the VBA editor, go to "View" and select "Locals Window".  Run your code, and then when it breaks on the error, look at what's in your "Locals" window.  Hopefully, you'll be able to figure out which variable is `Nothing` and causing the null reference error.

Comment: now it wont even allow me to run the code. as soon as I execute it, I get the object variable error.

Comment: ok here is where it broke:                                                                                       XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send